# .NET: How to create an Evtx file based on a List of Events

Tags: c#, .net, logging, event-log

I would like to know if there's a way to create a .EVTX or .EVT file from a collection of EventLogEntry objects or a EventLog object.

Here's my situation. I need to get all Events from a particular source (this I already know), create an .Evtx file from these events and then send this file to another person. But I'm stuck in the part where you create the .EVTX file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it really need to be that file format? PowerShell has Get-WinEvent and Export-Csv commandlets that let you first filter contents then output into CSV (or XML or other formats). If you need a solution to cover .Evtx specifically, I'm sorry for not answering that but I'm wondering if you really need to go that route when existing functionality exists to make what you're attempting much easier to me.

Comment: @w0rd-driven Unfortunately, the client wants the .evtx file, so that he can open the events on event viewer.

If there's any other way to open saved events on Event Viewer, I could use it to solve my problem.